# Adding force sideways ,want to subtract the same force applied when action is done

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a car,the turning sideways part is done by adding force to x axis,what 
I want to do is remove the force added when the action is done,so the car does not keep on moving sideways even when the action is done,please help thanks.

Edit: I am really sorry I should've given more information,I'm applying force towards z axis to move the car ahead and there are three status one is null one is  left and one is right,on left the force is applied towards x axis with negative value and same with right but with positive value,thing is I'm trying to deduct the same force when the status is null which is being applied even after the left or right status is false,the force just stays ,thus giving the car sideways movement even when the status is null,sorry mods and admins for the trouble.

Edit 2: I did it with the help of velocity of car with respect to x axis, did two if statements,one when it is greater than zero and one with lesser than zero ,used -Time.deltaTime to subtract when it is greater than zero,you can also multiply -Time.deltaTime to adjust the time taken to stop applying force.
Sorry Mods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set zero to car rigidbody velocity.

```
car.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

Comment: I wanted to change only x value of velocity to zero,now it is working ,thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see, then you know what to do. Cheers